# A function in printf in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

How can I call a function that has printf in it - in printf BUT without it printing the value entered twice?
in the code written below is how it is now, it prints the inserted value.
can I just use the function without printing the value again?

can I use printf(roll(num))

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int roll(int);
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("%d",roll(num));
    return 0;
}

int roll(int a)
{
    printf("Enter a number between 1-6:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a<1 || a>6)
    {
        printf("Wrong input! please enter a number between 1-6:\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, you're allowed to just print once, if you want to.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this compiles without any warnings or errors? You don't return anything from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function without printf.

```
    roll(num);
```

Comment: That must be the most pointless Q&A in history. I mean the answer is fine, and addresses the question, but why would anyone use `printf` if they don't want to print the result? How could you guess what was being asked?

Comment: They may be beginners who tries to mimic code online and doesn’t understand it. Everyone starts somewhere! His code probably will not compile too as there is no return in his roll function definition.

Comment: I added the return thank you for noticing. and yes I am a beginner :)